# Getting all arguments passed to a subroutine as a string in Perl

Tags: string, perl, arguments, parameter-passing, subroutine

I am trying to write a function that can take all of its arguments and print them as a string exactly as they were entered.

For example using the following function:

```
test('arg1' => $arg1, 'arg2' => $arg2);
```

I would like to get the following string inside of the function *formatted **EXACTLY** as seen below*:

```
"'arg1' => $arg1, 'arg2' => $arg2"
```

I want to do this so I can print all of the arguments the same way that they were entered for debugging/testing purposes.

Comment: Another example: say you wanted to do `test(time)`.  Simply printing `@_` will print the epoch value of the current time and its very unclear (at first glance) that you are actually testing the current time.

Comment: Use [Devel::Trace](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Trace), or just use the regular debugger and break at the line where the function is called.

Comment: See also [`Debug::Show`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Debug::Show), [`PadWalker`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PadWalker), [`Data::Dumper::Names`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper::Names), [`Data::Dumper::Lazy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper::Lazy) and [`Debug::ShowStuff::ShowVar`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Debug::ShowStuff::ShowVar)

Comment: It is also possible to parse the line using [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI) using information from [`caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html). But this runs into some other problems like determining the file name of the source file. See [this discussion](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=127646) for more information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl provides special [debugging hooks](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebguts.html#Debugger-Internals) that let you see the raw lines of compiled source files. You can write a custom debugger that prints the original line every time a subroutine is invoked.

The following lets you specify one or more subroutines you want to match; every time a matching subroutine is invoked, the corresponding line is printed.

```
package Devel::ShowCalls;

our %targets;

sub import {
    my $self = shift;

    for (@_) {
        # Prepend 'main::' for names without a package specifier
        $_ = "main::$_" unless /::/;
        $targets{$_} = 1;        
    }
}

package DB;

sub DB {
    ($package, $file, $line) = caller;
}

sub sub {
    print ">> $file:$line: ",
          ${ $main::{"_<$file"} }[$line] if $Devel::ShowCalls::targets{$sub};
    &$sub;
}

1;
```

---

To trace invocations of functions `foo` and `Baz::qux` in the following program:

```
sub foo {}
sub bar {}
sub Baz::qux {}

foo(now => time);
bar rand;
Baz::qux( qw/unicorn pony waffles/ );
```

Run:

```
$ perl -d:ShowCalls=foo,Baz::qux myscript.pl 
>> myscript.pl:5: foo(now => time);
>> myscript.pl:7: Baz::qux( qw/unicorn pony waffles/ );
```

Note that this will only print the first line of the invocation, so it won't work for calls like

```
foo( bar,
     baz );
```

Comment: The only problem is I want to use this to write a unit testing script.  Essentially I want my tests to each be named after their associated function and arguments that way I don't need to manually name each test.  Is there a way to do this without explicitly running Perl in debug mode?  or maybe invoke debug mode from within the test script itself?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 That approach will fail if you want to run multiple tests on the same function with the same input. For example, with `$foo->connect(); $foo->close(); $foo->close();`, you probably want the first `close` to close the connection, but you may want the second `close` to warn. Different behavior, but in your scheme, you'll have the exact same test name for both. The test name should be a human-readable string describing the expected behavior. Do any future maintenance programmers (including yourself!) a favor and write descriptive test names.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably not the best solution, but it works:

```
sub test {
    my (undef, $file_name, $line_number) = caller;
    open my $fh, '<', $file_name or die $!;
    my @lines = <$fh>;
    close $fh;

    my $line = $lines[$line_number - 1];
    trim($line);

    print $line."\n";
}

sub trim {
    return map { $_ =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g } @_;
}
```

Now when you run this:

```
test(time);
```

You will get this as the output:

> test(time);