# Which modern (post-5.10) trickery can be leveraged to make a Data::Dumper::Simple work-alike work?

Tags: perl, metaprogramming

Several dumpers exist that can show the names of variables without requiring the programmer to explicitely repeat the name.

```
› perl -MData::Dumper::Simple -e'my $foo = 42; print Dumper($foo)'
$foo = 42;
```

The trickery is a source filter (breaks often).

```
› perl -MDDS -e'my $foo = 42; DumpLex $foo'
$foo = 42;
```

The trickery is [PadWalker](https://metacpan.org/pod/PadWalker).

They also work to some extent with variables of other types, but slices or other complex expressions are problematic.

Which modern (post-5.10) trickery can be leveraged to make the following example dumper (as in: data structure viewer, not `eval`-able code producer) work? The point of emphasis is to always print nice names, to accept multiple expressions, and no need for changing expressions with an extra reference level.

```
use 5.020; use Syntax::Construct qw(%slice);
use strictures;
use Acme::Hypothetical::Dumper 'd';

my %foo = (
    Me => 'person',
    You => 'beloved one',
    Them => 'space aliens',
);

d %foo, $foo{'Me'}, @foo{qw(You Me)}, %foo{qw(You Me)};
# %foo = ('Me' => 'person', 'Them' => 'space aliens', 'You' => 'beloved one');
# $foo{'Me'} = 'person';
# @foo{qw(You Me)} = ('beloved one', 'person');
# %foo{qw(You Me)} = ('Me' => 'person', 'You' => 'beloved one');

my @bar = qw(Me You Them);

d @bar, $bar[0], @bar[2, 1], %bar[2, 1];
# @bar = ('Me', 'You', 'Them');
# $bar[0] = 'Me';
# @bar[2, 1] = ('Them', 'You');
# %bar[2, 1] = (2 => 'Them', 1 => 'You');

use LWP::UserAgent qw();
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
d $ua->{ssl_opts}{verify_hostname};
# $ua->{ssl_opts}{verify_hostname} = 1;
```

Comment: This smells like an XY problem to me. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: How about reading your own source code, much like the error screen of a Mojolicious app does.

Comment: Isn't that Data::Printer?

Comment: @briandfoy nope, Data::Printer does not know variable names.

Comment: and what about `Data::TreeDumper` but I suppose that is just a _"newer"_ `Data::Dumper`

Comment: Yes this feature would be nice to have. I [started implementing](https://github.com/garu/Data-Printer/pull/74) something like this for `Data::Printer` using `PPI` two years ago. Damian has recently come up with a more efficient Perl parser in his `PPR` module, see [`Data::Dx`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dx). See also [Getting all arguments passed to a subroutine as a string in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36361651/2173773) for some other links.

Comment: This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361651/getting-all-arguments-passed-to-a-subroutine-as-a-string-in-perl), but not quite.

Comment: Best way might be to get subroutine call opcode (using perlapi func `caller_cx`???), locate the argument opcodes (through standard opcode tree navigation), and somehow pass them to B::Deparse.

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace in the output doesn't perfectly match your examples, but this is pretty close...

```
use v5.14;
use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN {
    package Acme::Hypothetical::Dumper;
    use Keyword::Simple;
    use PPR;
    use Data::Dumper;
    use B 'perlstring';
    
    sub import {
        my ( $class, $fname ) = ( shift, @_ );
        $fname ||= 'd';
        
        Keyword::Simple::define $fname => sub {
            my $code = shift;
            my ( @ws, @vars, @ws2 );
            while ( $$code =~ / ^ ((?&PerlOWS)) ((?&PerlTerm)) ((?&PerlOWS)) $PPR::GRAMMAR /x ) {
                my $len = length( $1 . $2 . $3 );
                push @ws, $1;
                push @vars, $2;
                push @ws2, $3;
                substr( $$code, 0, $len ) = '';
                $$code =~ s/ ^ (?&PerlComma) $PPR::GRAMMAR //x;
            }
            my $newcode = perlstring( $class ) . '->d(';
            while ( @vars ) {
                my $var = shift @vars;
                $newcode .= sprintf(
                    '%s%s,[%s],%s',
                    shift( @ws ),
                    perlstring( $var ),
                    $var,
                    shift( @ws2 ),
                );
            }
            $newcode .= ');';
            substr( $$code, 0, 0 ) = $newcode;
            return;
        };
    }
    
    our $OUTPUT = \*STDERR;
    
    sub d {
        my ( $class, @args ) = ( shift, @_ );
        while ( @args ) {
            my ( $label, $value ) = splice( @args, 0, 2 );
            
            my $method = 'dump_list';
            if ( $label =~ /^\$/ ) {
                $method = 'dump_scalar';
                $value  = $value->[0];
            }
            elsif ( $label =~ /^\%/ ) {
                $method = 'dump_hash';
            }
            
            printf { $OUTPUT } "%s = %s;\n", $label, $class->$method( $value );
        }
    }
    
    sub dump_scalar {
        my ( $class, $value ) = ( shift, @_ );
        local $Data::Dumper::Terse  = 1;
        local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
        return Dumper( $value );
    }
    
    sub dump_list {
        my ( $class, $value ) = ( shift, @_ );
        my $dumped = $class->dump_scalar( $value );
        $dumped =~ s/\[/(/;
        $dumped =~ s/\]/)/;
        return $dumped;
    }

    sub dump_hash {
        my ( $class, $value ) = ( shift, @_ );
        my $dumped = $class->dump_scalar( { @$value } );
        $dumped =~ s/\{/(/;
        $dumped =~ s/\}/)/;
        return $dumped;
    }

    $INC{'Acme/Hypothetical/Dumper.pm'} = __FILE__;
};

use Acme::Hypothetical::Dumper 'd';

my %foo = (
    Me => 'person',
    You => 'beloved one',
    Them => 'space aliens',
);

d %foo, $foo{'Me'}, @foo{qw(You Me)}, %foo{qw(You Me)};

my @bar = qw(Me You Them);

d @bar, $bar[0], @bar[2, 1], %bar[2, 1];

use LWP::UserAgent qw();
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

d $ua->{ssl_opts}{verify_hostname};
```

Comment: PS: if you wonder why I save whitespace into `@ws` and `@ws2` and then carefully insert it back into the generated code, it's because whitespace can include linebreaks, and I'm trying to avoid breaking line numbers in error messages.