# how can I display a variable's name in perl, along with the value of the variable?

Tags: perl, subroutine, declare

To diagnose or debug my perl code, I would like to easily display the name of a variable along with its value. In `bash`, one types the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
dog=pitbull
declare -p dog
```

In `perl`, consider the following script, `junk.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings; 
my $dog="pitbull";
my $diagnosticstring;
print STDERR "dog=$dog\n";
sub checkvariable {
    foreach $diagnosticstring (@_) { print "nameofdiagnosticstring=$diagnosticstring\n"; }
}
checkvariable "$dog";
```

If we call this script, we obtain

```
bash> junk.pl
dog=pitbull
nameofdiagnosticstring=pitbull
bash>
```

But instead, when the subroutine `checkvariable` is called, I would like the following to be printed:

```
dog=pitbull
```

This would make coding easier and less error-prone, since one would not have to type the variable's name twice.

Comment: See also [Getting all arguments passed to a subroutine as a string in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36361651/2173773)

Comment: [Debug::Show](https://metacpan.org/pod/Debug::Show) or [Debug::ShowStuff::ShowVar](https://metacpan.org/pod/Debug::ShowStuff::ShowVar) looks promising

Comment: I also created a pull request to [Data::Printer](https://github.com/garu/Data-Printer/pull/74) 4 years ago that does this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this with [PadWalker](https://metacpan.org/pod/PadWalker) (which you'll need to install from CPAN). But it's almost certainly far more complex than you'd like it to be.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings; 
use PadWalker 'peek_my';

my $dog="pitbull";
print STDERR "dog=$dog\n";
sub checkvariable {
  my $h = peek_my(0);
  foreach (@_) {
    print '$', $_,'=', ${$h->{'$'. $_}}, "\n";
  }
}
checkvariable "dog";
```

Answer (score 3):

[Data::Dumper::Names](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Data-Dumper-Names/lib/Data/Dumper/Names.pm) may be what you're looking for.

```
#! perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper::Names;

my $dog = 'pitbull';
my $cat = 'lynx';
my @mice = qw(jumping brown field);

checkvariable($dog, $cat, \@mice);

sub checkvariable {
    print Dumper @_;
}

1;
```

Output:

```
perl test.pl

$dog = 'pitbull';
$cat = 'lynx';
@mice = (
          'jumping',
          'brown',
          'field'
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

(not an answer, a formatted comment)

The checkvariable sub receives only a value, and there's no (simple or reliable) way to find out what *variable* holds that *value*.

This is why Data::Dumper forces you to specify the varnames as strings:

```sh
perl -MData::Dumper -E '
  my $x = 42;
  my $y = "x";
  say Data::Dumper->Dump([$x, $y]);
  say Data::Dumper->Dump([$x, $y], [qw/x y/])
'
```

```
$VAR1 = 42;
$VAR2 = 'x';

$x = 42;
$y = 'x';
```

Answer (score 0):

Something as following usually helps

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 1;

my $container = 20;
my %hash      = ( 'a' => 7, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 0 );
my @array     = [ 1, 7, 9, 8, 21, 16, 37, 42];

debug('container',$container) if $debug;
debug('%hash',  \%hash)       if $debug;
debug('@array', @array)       if $debug;

sub debug {
    my $name  = shift;
    my $value = shift;

    print "DEBUG: $name [ARRAY]\n", Dumper($value) if ref $value eq 'ARRAY';
    print "DEBUG: $name [HASH]\n",  Dumper($value) if ref $value eq 'HASH';
    print "DEBUG: $name = $value\n"                if ref $value eq '';
}
```

But why not run perl script under build-in debugger? Option **-d**

[The Perl Debugger](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html)